# I want to make a timer for a variable to reset the value while the loop continues, python

Tags: python, loops, time, while-loop, timer

```
import time

x = 0

while True:
 
 print(x)
 x+=1
 time.sleep(5)

 if x == 50:
   #run a timer while x is still printing until the timer goes down to 0, then it automatically resets x
```

Comment: So you want it to get to 50, then start over?

Comment: if you already use `sleep`, what is the point of using a timer, if you already can calculate when it will end and just instead check when it reaches the calculated value to reset it, for example if the timer is set to 10 seconds, then just do `if x == 50 + 10 / 5: x = 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
counter = 0
while True:
    print('\r',counter,end=' ')
    counter +=1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if counter == 5+2:
        counter = 0
        time.sleep(5)


counter = 0
while True:
    mins,secs = divmod(counter,60)
    timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins,secs)
    counter += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('\r',timer,end='')
    if counter == 5+2:
        counter = 0
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: @Matiiss I don't follow... pls clarify

Comment: The grammar is off, but from what I gleaned, once the timer reaches 50, it resets back to 0. Isn't that what my code does?

Comment: yeah, I never thought of that interpretation, so it could be that

Comment: sorry my english is not that great but I will try to explain it better, i do not want it to reset it to 0, I want to began resetting wants it enters 50.

Comment: so for example, every sencond it prints a number, so 1 2 3 4 5 when it enters 5 it will take 5 seconds untill the variable is changed, so it will print like this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8 9 10 1 2 3 4 etc. does make more sence?

Comment: Been on it a lot and can't figure it out. I've updated my answer, but I still cant get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
start = time.time()

x = 0

while True:
    while time.time() - start < 1:
        print(x)
        x+=1
    x=0
    start = time.time()
```

This will reset your x value every one second.